# Undo a commit on Github?

Tags: git, github

I have local repository setup with 2 branches `master` and `sandbox`.
I made changes on sandbox: 
1. Changes for the working version and, 
2. Changes to get the version working on my Windows machine.

I committed the changes separately, first `1` then `2`.
I then merged the `master` branch with the `sandbox` branch.

Now because I wanted to ignore change set `2` (changes to get working on Windows), I created a `.gitignore` with the following content.

```
$ cat .gitignore

#changed for local
conn.php
.htaccess
```

I then pushed the `master` branch to the remote master on GitHub, but now looking at the last 2 commits they are local machine development envonment changes (`2`).

And, I created my `.gitignore` with `notepad++` but it is not hidden and looks like a textfile.

So, I would like to undo the last 2 commits on the `github remote repository`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the reset --hard command but be warned that it will wipe out any uncommitted changes in your working copy.  Find the sha1 of the commit you want your branch to point at (I.e. before the last 2 commits) then use:

```
git reset --hard abcdef1234
```

Where abcdef1234 is the sha1 of the commit you want to go back to.  Afterwards you might have to force push your changes to the remote with:

```
git push -f origin sandbox
```

Or master, depending on which branch you are modifying

Comment: note that if someone already pulled from that repository, he is not going to see the removal (at first) and then will either get merges (when pulling) or errors (when pushing)